# Xcode File Templates: How to add file to existing group in the project?

Tags: xcode, templates

I'm trying to make custom file template for Xcode which would create multiple files and should distribute them to already existing groups.

For simplicity, I only show one file and one directory in the examples.

I followed tutorials on how to create templates like [this](https://gigigo.com/2017/05/05/templates-as-a-way-of-life/?lang=en) or [this](https://blog.showoff.ie/xcode-custom-project-templates-basics-1e0f1f673a7f).

I tried modifying paths, keys, adding Targets but none of them helped.

My templates `.plist` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.IDEKit.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
    <key>Platforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
    </array>
    <key>Options</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>productName</string>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Name:</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Some Description</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
            <key>Default</key>
            <string>Name</string>
            <key>Utils</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Swift</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Nodes</key>
                    <array>
            <string>GroupName/___FILEBASENAME___Suffix.swift</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Definitions</key>
    <dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>GroupName</string>
        </dict>
    <key>GroupName/___FILEBASENAME___Suffix.swift</key>
        <dict>
      <key>Path</key>
            <string>GroupName/___FILEBASENAME___Suffix.swift</string>
            <key>Group</key>
            <array>
                <string>GroupName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My `.xctemplate` folder structure is:

```
-> GroupName
|-> ___FILEBASENAME___Suffix.swift
TemplateIcon.png
TemplateIcon@2x.png
TemplateInfo.plist
```

After adding my template to the project which already have `GroupName` group, I can see that the file is added to the folder (when I check it in the Finder) but it's not being added to the `project.pbxproj` and because of that, I can't see it in my project tree.

If, however, I don't have `GroupName` group in the project yet, this will create a folder (blue icon instead of yellow for the group) with the file in, which I can then see in my project tree.